# How to run multiple table loads in parallel in Azure Databrics

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

My driver program gets the list of table in JSON format
Eg:["A","B","C"]

Current process:

1. Each table  in the list are independent and each table has one or
   two Txn .
2. Each table are loaded in sequentially and all  extraction ,Txn  and loading  are performed using Spark Data frame operations
3. However we wanted to implement to load all tables in parallel ,To achieve a parallelism, Should we change any configuration spark configuration in azure databrics
   Note:
   If we explicitly set scheduler mode "Fair" with new pool,We are getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you iterate through [Scala parallel collection](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html), Spark jobs can be launched in parallel. Just a dummy example:

```
Seq("A", "B", "C").par.foreach { t =>
  spark.read.text(s"$t.txt").load().write.saveAsTable(t)
}
```

Note the `.par` that converts Seq into its parallel version.